# .Net WebAPI URI convention for advanced searching /filtering

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am relatively new to REST and WebAPI by Microsoft. We are implementing a hub REST service that will house several types of object gets and sets. Being the lead on the project, I am being tasked with coming up with the proper Uri design we are going with. I was wondering what thoughts were on war is better. Yes I specifically phased that without using the word "standard".

Here are the options my team and I are currently entertaining:

```
Http://servername/API/REST/Ldap/AD/employees?username=jsmith 
Http://servername/API/REST/Ldap/AD/employee/UserName?searchTerm=jsmith (this seems RPC to me)
Http://servername/API/REST/Ldap/AD/employees/getusername?searchterm?jsmith
```

We are also creating a Soap version hence the rest in the Uri.

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Oppositional's comment, this is what I put together some time ago.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/servicestack/uoMzASmvxho/CtqpZdju7NcJ

```cs
public class QueryBase
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
}

[Route("/v1/users")]
public class User : IReturn<List<User>>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class RequestFilterAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    #region IHasRequestFilter Members

    public IHasRequestFilter Copy()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public int Priority
    {
        get { return -100; }
    }

public void RequestFilter(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
{
    var query = req.QueryString["q"] ?? req.QueryString["query"];
    var limit = req.QueryString["limit"];
    var offset = req.QueryString["offset"];

    var user = requestDto as QueryBase;
    if (user == null) { return; }
    user.Query = query;
    user.Limit = limit.IsEmpty() ? int.MaxValue : int.Parse(limit);
    user.Offset = offset.IsEmpty() ? 0 : int.Parse(offset);
    }

#endregion
}

[Route("/v1/users/search", "GET")]
[RequestFilter]
public class SearchUser : QueryBase, IReturn<PagedResult<User>> { }

public class UsersService : Service
{
    public static List<User> UserRepository = new List<User>
    {
        new User{ Id="1", FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "A", Email = "michaelEmail" },
        new User{ Id="2", FirstName = "Robert", LastName = "B", Email = "RobertEmail" },
        new User{ Id="3", FirstName = "Khris", LastName = "C", Email = "KhrisEmail" },
        new User{ Id="4", FirstName = "John", LastName = "D", Email = "JohnEmail" },
        new User{ Id="4", FirstName = "Lisa", LastName = "E", Email = "LisaEmail" }
    };

    public PagedResult<User> Get(SearchUser request)
{
    var query = request.Query;
    var users = request.Query.IsNullOrEmpty()
                    ? UserRepository.ToList()
                    : UserRepository.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(query) || x.LastName.Contains(query) || x.Email.Contains(query)).ToList();

    var totalItems = users.Count;
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)request.Limit);
    var currentPage = request.Offset;
    users = users.Skip(request.Offset * request.Limit).Take(request.Limit).ToList();
    var itemCount = users.Count;

    return new PagedResult<User>
        {
            TotalItems = totalItems,
            TotalPages = totalPages,
            ItemCount = itemCount,
            Items = users,
            CurrentPage = currentPage
        };
}
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I recommend you take a look at [Web API Design](https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf) from Brian Mulloy. He has several recommendations when it comes to searching and filtering.

**Simplify associations - sweep complexity under the ‘?’**

> Most APIs have intricacies beyond the base level of a resource.
>   Complexities can include many states that can be updated, changed,
>   queried, as well as the attributes associated with a resource. Make it
>   simple for developers to use the base URL by putting optional states
>   and attributes behind the HTTP question mark. Keep your API intuitive
>   by simplifying the associations between resources, and sweeping
>   parameters and other complexities under the rug of the HTTP question
>   mark.

**Tips for search**

> While a simple search could be modeled as a resourceful API (for
>   example, dogs/?q=red), a more complex search across multiple resources
>   requires a different design. If you want to do a global search across
>   resources, we suggest you follow the Google model:
>
> *Global search*
>
> /search?q=fluffy+fur
>
> Here, search is the verb; ?q represents the query.
>
> *Scoped search*
>
> To add scope to your search, you can prepend with the scope of the
>   search. For example, search in dogs owned by resource ID 5678
>
> /owners/5678/dogs?q=fluffy+fur
>
> Notice that the explicit search has been dropped from the URL and
>   instead it relies on the parameter 'q' to indicate the scoped query.

**Pagination and partial response**

> Support partial response by adding optional fields in a *comma
>   delimited list*.
>
> /dogs?fields=name,color,location
>
> Use *limit* and *offset* to make it easy for developers to paginate
>   objects.
>
> /dogs?limit=25&offset=50

Comment: @Oppositinal - Thank you very much this is great info. Now the other thing I'm trying to reason out is something a validation call. for instance if i want to offer the developer a validate ticket number, should I have a verb in the url in this case like http://serverName/tickets/validate?ticketNumber=1233 or http://serverName/tickets?validate&ticketNumber=1233 or just http://serverName/tickets/1233 and they would get a nil back?? What would your take be on something like that?

Comment: Assuming the ticket number is the unique identifier for the ticket resource, my take would be to perform a GET to /api/v1/tickets/1233 and return a 404 status if a ticket with that number does not exist. If you look at the API guidance I linked to, it recommends that for API calls that send a response that is not a resource per se (does not invlove a resource returned from a data store), you should use verbs not nouns, such as /api/v1/validate?ticketId=1233

Comment: Linked document seems to be behind some login-wall, any other locations for this reference?